# How to replace a hardware modem by virtual modem

Tags: linux, serial, modem

I have an embedded device that is connected by an old dial-up modem to 
the Internet. I cannot change the embedded device but would like to 
connect the embedded device to a Linux machine that has an Internet 
connection. The Linux machine has a free RS232 port that I would like to 
use. It should offer a virtual modem that behaves just as a normal 
dial-up modem including a PPP server that allows the embedded device to 
set up a PPP connection.

If I could make a wish, I would prefer a new device pppN that I could 
use with normal routing and firewalling.

What is a quick way to do so? What is the best way to do so? Are there 
better alternatives using RS232 that might require minor changes to the 
embedded device?

Update:
I actually now simply use pppd as described here:
http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/PPP-HOWTO/direct.html

However, I like tcpser and I am pretty sure I will use it for another project sooner then later.

Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Look here : http://www.jagshouse.com/modem.html, I believe your best solution would be to simulate a phone line and then just connect another dial up modem to your Linux machine and connect your embedded device to that. Theoretically it should also be possible to make a modem using a sound card but I haven't found any up to date softmodem implementations on which you'd be able to run ppp on.

Comment: [Also related](http://superuser.com/questions/263119/connecting-two-computers-via-modems-rj11).

Comment: You may want to look at old software for this.  At the time of BBS'es there was a lot of effort in attaching legacy BBS'es to the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to say I didn't know of any such program, but 20 seconds of googling turned up [tcpser](http://manned.org/tcpser/e8754729)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JagR software to configure your device from the machine using the external port.
It will allow you ppp connection setup and then a firewall and stable internet connection can be established.
Good luck.